# How can I print the name of the antepenultimate folder of a directory? bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to print the name of the antepenultimate folder for multiple directories within a for loop.
I would like to know if there is a way to get this name easily.

Example:

```
array=(/ a / b / c / d / e / f / g / h / i / j)
```

The folder that I'm trying to print is h (The position of folder h is always the same but the name is different.

Comment: You show an array but a path would be a string. Perhaps show what you have done so far and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Subtract 5 from the length of the array to get the array index.

```
echo "${array[${#array[@]}-5]}"
```

Or in modern versions of bash simply:

```
echo "${array[-5]}"
```

Comment: how about this : `echo "${array[$((${#array[@]} - 5))]}"` ?

Comment: That will work, but `$(())` is unnecessary because array indexes are automatically evaluated as arithmetic expressions.

Comment: Modern Bash support negative indexing. You can do `${array[-5]}` in this case.

Comment: Thank you, I have another doubt, If I want to save the name of a new file with the name of this directory: directory_data.txt can I do it like this: ${array[${#array[@]}-5]}_data.txt ?

Comment: Sure. You can use it like any other variable.

Answer (score 0):

`$(( ))` is the syntax to enter a math context.

```
echo "${array[$((${#array[@]} - 5))]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really have an array with single letter folder names and the path delimiters to represent a path. (Which is the wrong way btw to do this)

With "modern bash" (ie, version 4.1 released in 2009 or later versions) you can use negative indexing to return from the end:

```
$ array=(/ a / b / c / d / e / f / g / h / i / j)
$ echo "${array[-5]}"
h
```

(That also works under `zsh` where calculating the length and subtract does not since `zsh` has base 1 arrays and `Bash` has base 0 arrays...)

However, most paths are strings and it is usually easier to manipulate the string representing a path. Your array method breaks if the individual folder names are not single letters.

Suppose you have a path represented as:

```
$ path="/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j"
```

You can use [Bash string manipulation functions](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) to retrieve that position as so:

```
$ s1="${path%/*/*}"          # remove the last two directories 
$ echo "${s1##*/}"           # remove all directories up to the last
h
```

The advantage of the string method is the `/` acts as a true delimiter between folder names of arbitrary length.

Consider:

```
$ path="/Foulder_a/sub_b/c/AND_d/e/this_is_f/and_this_is_g/THIS_ONE_I_WANT_h/penultimate/last"
$ s1="${path%/*/*}"
$ echo "${s1##*/}"
THIS_ONE_I_WANT_h
```

Try and do that with the array method...

---

From comments:

```
$ path="/a/sub_b/c/AND_d/e/the_f/this_is_g/THIS_ONE_I_WANT_h/penultimate/last"
$ s1="${path%/*/*}"
$ name="${s1##*/}"
$ new_path="${s1}/${name}.txt"
$ echo "$new_path"
/a/sub_b/c/AND_d/e/the_f/this_is_g/THIS_ONE_I_WANT_h/THIS_ONE_I_WANT_h.txt
```

Comment: Thanks I used bash string manipulation and it works. I have a doubt if I try to save a file with the name of this directory can I save it as: ${s1##*/}_data.txt?

Comment: Suppose you want to save `X.txt` into directory `h` and you have the full or relative path string in `path` you can do If you want the full path the directory `h` for example, just do `new_path="${path%/*/*}/X.txt"`

Comment: Thank you, I am wondering if there is a way of saving a file with the name of the directory <h> like this: h_data.txt